# SSE instruction within nested for loops

Tags: c++, intel, sse

i have several nested for loops in my code and i try to use intel SSE instructions on an intel i7 core to speed up the application.
The code structure is as follows (val is set in a higher for loop):

```
_m128 in1,in2,tmp1,tmp2,out;
float arr[4] __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
val = ...;

... several higher for loops ...
for(f=0; f<=fend; f=f+4){
    index2 = ...;
    for(i=0; i<iend; i++){
        for(j=0; j<jend; j++){
            inputval = ...;
            index = ...;
            if(f<fend-4){
                arr[0] = array[index];
                arr[1] = array[index+val];
                arr[2] = array[index+2*val];
                arr[3] = array[index+3*val];
                in1  = _mm_load_ps(arr);
                in2  = _mm_set_ps1(inputval);
                tmp1 = _mm_mul_ps(in1, in2);
                tmp2 = _mm_loadu_ps(&array2[index2]);
                out  = _mm_add_ps(tmp1,tmp2);
                _mm_storeu_ps(&array2[index2], out);
            } else {
                //if no 4 values available for SSE instruction execution execute serial code
                for(int u = 0; u < fend-f; u++ ) array2[index2+u] += array[index+u*val] * inputval;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think there are two main problems: the buffer used for aligning the values from 'array', and the fact that when no 4 values are left (e.g. when fend = 6, two values are left over which should be executed with the sequential code). Is there any other way of loading the values from in1 and/or executing SSE intructions with 3 or 2 values?

---

Thanks for the answers so far. The loading is as good as it gets i think, but is there any workaround for the 'leftover' part within the else statement that could be solved using SSE instructions?

Answer (score 2):

I think the bigger problem is that there is so little computation for such a massive amount of data movement:

```
arr[0] = array[index];                   //  Data Movement
arr[1] = array[index+val];               //  Data Movement
arr[2] = array[index+2*val];             //  Data Movement
arr[3] = array[index+3*val];             //  Data Movement
in1  = _mm_load_ps(arr);                 //  Data Movement
in2  = _mm_set_ps1(inputval);            //  Data Movement
tmp1 = _mm_mul_ps(in1, in2);             //  Computation
tmp2 = _mm_loadu_ps(&array2[index2]);    //  Data Movement
out  = _mm_add_ps(tmp1,tmp2);            //  Computation
_mm_storeu_ps(&array2[index2], out);     //  Data Movement
```

While it "might" be possible to simplify this. I'm not at all convinced that vectorization is going to be beneficial at all in this situation.

You'll have to change your data layout to make avoid the strided access `index + n*val`.

Or you can wait until AVX2 gather/scatter instructions become available in 2013?

Comment: I know the data movement part is the biggest problem, but still with the code i have now the application benefits from it. I was just curious if there were some other ways to be able to gain more performance.

Comment: Paul R's answer is what I'd try next. The main thing you want to avoid is what you're doing right now with the aligned buffer. There tends to be a very big penalty for immediately re-accessing recently stored memory with a different word-size.

Comment: Oops, I misread part of the code so my edit didn't make any sense. So I've rolled it back.

Comment: You can already try AVX2 using Intel SDE and see if you'll gain performance in terms of number of operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can express this:

```
            arr[0] = array[index];
            arr[1] = array[index+val];
            arr[2] = array[index+2*val];
            arr[3] = array[index+3*val];
            in1  = _mm_load_ps(arr);
```

more succinctly as:

```
            in1  = _mm_set_ps(array[index+3*val], array[index+2*val], array[index+val], array[index]);
```

and get rid of `arr`, which *might* give the compiler some opportunity to optimise away some redundant loads/stores.

However your data organisation is the main problem, compounded by the fact that you are doing almost no computation relative to the number of loads and stores, two of which are unaligned. If possible you need to re-organise your data structures so that you can load and store 4 elements at a time form aligned contiguous memory in all cases, otherwise any computational benefits will tend to be outweighed by inefficient memory access patterns.

Comment: +1, since you clearly beat me to this solution of using `_mm_set_ps` instead of the aligned buffer.

Comment: Thanks - it's pretty rare that I get to respond to a SIMD question before you these days - don't you ever sleep ? ;-)

Comment: I'm a student, so my sleep schedule is dictated by my class schedule and is as volatile as the weather here in the midwest... :)

Comment: This code could potentially generate 5 loads and 4 store operations and this could be a WAY too big overhead. One should implement preamble  loop to align load operations. You could find such examples in different Intel optimization manuals.

Comment: @Elalfer: thanks for the comment and the down-vote, but you need to look at the question before criticising - it's not possible to make all the loads aligned with the existing data organisations so a preamble loop won't help. And the *gather* operation which I was trying to address above is the biggest problem, and there is no simple solution for that other than re-structuring the data.

Comment: You are right, sorry... I missed "*val" index parameter. AVX2 will provide gather operations. Until then, I'm not sure it make sense to vectorize current code without rearranging data structures.

Answer (score 0):

if you want full benefit form SSE (factor 4 or more faster than best optimised code without explicit usage of SSE), you **must** ensure that your data layout such that you only ever need aligned loads and stores. Though using _mm_set_ps(w,z,y,x) in your code snippet may help, you should avoid the need for this, i.e. avoid strided accesses (they are less efficient than a single _mm_load_ps).

As for the problem of the last few<4 elements, I usually ensure that all my data are not only 16-byte aligned, but also array sizes are multiples of 16 bytes, such that I never have such spare remaining elements. Of course, the real problem may have spare elements, but that data can usually be set such that they don't cause a problem (set to the neutral elements, i.e. zero for additive operations). In rare cases, you only want to work on a subset of the array which starts and/or ends at an unaligned position. In this case one may use bitwise operations (_mm_and_ps, _mm_or_ps) to suppress operations on the unwanted elements.